# Do client requests between React and Node, both in separated Docker containers

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, express, docker-compose

I'm not able to do client (browser) requests between React app and Express app. I want to attach/validate a header token to each request I also want to be able to just console.log each request.

I’m developing a React frontend with a Express-GraphQL backend. While developing I need to log request headers coming to the server from client, mostly to ensure I’m on the right path. All tutorials just lay down the code, no debugging and such, everything just works.

This isn’t working in my current setup with CRA, Express and Docker. I’m perfectly able to log requests/send responses to endpoints.

The two applications runs in two separated containers. I’ve been trying to use both links, depends_on and networks in my Docker setup. Possibly wrong tho. But my client both depends on and links to my server. The server is running on port 8000, the client 3000.

To log client requests:

```
// Debugging
server.express.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req);
  next();
});
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  server:
    build:
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    expose:
      - 8000
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - ./server:/server
      - /server/node_modules
    networks:
      - webapp-network
  client:
    build:
      context: ./client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    expose:
      - 3000
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./client:/client
      - /client/node_modules
    networks:
      - webapp-network

networks:
  webapp-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Dockerfiles for client and server

```
FROM node:11-alpine
WORKDIR /server
COPY package.json ./
RUN yarn install
EXPOSE 8000
CMD [ "yarn", "dev" ]
```

```
FROM node:11-alpine
WORKDIR /client
COPY package.json ./
RUN yarn install
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "yarn", "start" ]
```

I suspect there is nothing wrong with my Docker config since I don’t get any errors and being able to log specific endpoint requests, but with my devops knowledge. I have a hard time separating my own host and the image host. Where am I suppose to reach both my frontend and still log requests to my backend? Do I really need a Nginx proxy for development purposes?

The funny thing is, I’ve been poking around with Next.js and a custom server, with that setup this particular scenario just works. I spin up both the Express server and Next, and then I’m all good, but I don’t need Nextjs for my smaller projects. I’ve been searching through Nextjs codebase for any hints. How is it handled with that setup?

Updated with server.js file:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const createServer = require('./createServer');
const server = createServer();

// Middleware

// Debugging
server.express.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log('req');
  next();
});

server.start({ port: process.env.PORT /* 8000 */ }, server =>
  console.log(`Listen to ${server.port}`)
);
```

I've also tried not using a middleware, ie.

```
server.get('*', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req);
});
```

```
server.express.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req);
});
```

Updated with create server fn.

```
const { prisma } = require('../generated/prisma-client');
const { GraphQLServer } = require('graphql-yoga');
const Query = require('./resolvers/Query');
const Mutation = require('./resolvers/Mutation');

function createServer() {
  return new GraphQLServer({
    typeDefs: './src/schema.graphql',
    resolvers: {
      Query,
      Mutation
    },
    context: request => {
      return {
        ...request,
        prisma
      };
    },
    debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
    resolverValidationOptions: { requireResolversForResolveType: false }
  });
}

module.exports = createServer;
```

Comment: I am confused, what happens when you try to reach the server from the client? Timeout? Error? Also, try launching the containers with docker-compose but do not set it in detached mode , that way any errors will show up in that terminal window.

Comment: Different ports means you will need to enable CORS in your back end app

Comment: Nothing happens, I’m accessing the frontend from localhost:3000, but there is no logging server side. If I hit an endpoint (/api/whatevs) using Fetch API the server is logging it.  But with the express middleware there should be a logging on each request, at each endpoint (/, /hello etc.). That is how I’m using it in Nextjs.

Comment: I’ll try CORS, but if it was a CORS issue there should be an error.

Comment: Can you put the code of your `server.js` file?  I did not get if you are using `apollo-server-express` package or `apollo-server` and `express` packages separately.

Comment: Yes. Since I just started out, and got stuck pretty quickly. I've updated the question.

Comment: Added another update with the function that actually creates the server.